# bibtex2html options in org-mode publishing

Tags: org-mode, bibtex

How do I pass the bibtex2html option -nobibsource when publishing via ox-bibtex.el? I have added it directly to the ox-bibtex.el file by commentling out line 265 and adding my own:

```
;;'("-a" "-nodoc" "-noheader" "-nofooter")
'("-a" "-nodoc" "-noheader" "-nofooter" "-nobibsource")
```

I'm sure this isn't the right way to do it. I'm using org 8.3beta.

Answer (score 5):

```
(setq bibtex2html-program "/path/to/bibtex2html -nobibsource")
```

Sorry for answering my own question.